# Get selected class in a "ul"

Tags: jquery, selecteditem

How can I get the selected class of the li-item in with this code?

Now it loops all of the classes inside the ul, not just the selected.

```
$('<div id="chooseCustomFields'
  + field_id
  + '" class="wrapper-customfields" tabindex="1"><span>Choose Type</span>'
  + '<ul id="chooseCustomField'
  + field_id
  + '" class="dropdown">'
  + '<li class="chooseCheckbox"><i class="fa-icon-check"></i>Checkbox</li>'
  + '<li class="chooseAlternatives"><i class="fa-icon-list-ul"></i> Alternatives</li>'
  + '<li class="chooseDropdown"><i class="fa-icon-list-alt"></i> Dropdown</li>'
  + '<li class="chooseTextField"><i class="fa-icon-font"></i> Text</li>'
  + '</ul></div>').appendTo(field_secondchild).addClass("metro three-d")
.click(function() {
$('#chooseCustomField' + field_id + ' li').each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('class'))
});
});
```

Comment: do you want the clicked `li`

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get the clicked 'li'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want the clicked `li`

```
$('<div id="chooseCustomFields'
  + field_id
  + '" class="wrapper-customfields" tabindex="1"><span>Choose Type</span>'
  + '<ul id="chooseCustomField'
  + field_id
  + '" class="dropdown">'
  + '<li class="chooseCheckbox"><i class="fa-icon-check"></i>Checkbox</li>'
  + '<li class="chooseAlternatives"><i class="fa-icon-list-ul"></i> Alternatives</li>'
  + '<li class="chooseDropdown"><i class="fa-icon-list-alt"></i> Dropdown</li>'
  + '<li class="chooseTextField"><i class="fa-icon-font"></i> Text</li>'
  + '</ul></div>').appendTo(field_secondchild).addClass("metro three-d")
.on('click', 'li', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('class'))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html is poorly formatted as it is, so i fixed that, then i separated the html and js so we can see this actually working.

Here is the working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/acturbo/LmXz4/1/

**javascript:**

```
var field_id = "#chooseCustomField" + "555";
var field_secondchild = "#secondchild";

// new logic
$(field_id).appendTo( field_secondchild ).addClass( "metro three-d");

// easier way to assign a click event to each li
$(field_id + ' li').on("click", function() {
    alert($(this).attr('class'))
});
```

**html (needed for testing)**

```
<div id="secondchild">
    <p>for testing only</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>should be last</p>
</div>

<div id="chooseCustomFields555" class="wrapper-customfields" tabindex="1">
  <span>Choose Type</span>
  <ul id="chooseCustomField555" class="dropdown">
    <li class="chooseCheckbox"><i class="fa-icon-check"></i>Checkbox</li>
    <li class="chooseAlternatives"><i class="fa-icon-list-ul"></i> Alternatives</li>
    <li class="chooseDropdown"><i class="fa-icon-list-alt"></i> Dropdown</li>
    <li class="chooseTextField"><i class="fa-icon-font"></i> Text</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```